# Is it ok to inject TestScope into Android tests using Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-testing, dagger-hilt

I am using android injection library Hilt to inject my `testScope`,`testDispatcher` and `testScheduler` into tests.

The test seems to be working for now but it seems like a code smell and I am unsure if this could lead to problems down the line.

Is it ok to inject the test variables this way?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FakeModule {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTestScheduler(): TestCoroutineScheduler = TestCoroutineScheduler()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTestDispatcher(scheduler: TestCoroutineScheduler): TestDispatcher =
    UnconfinedTestDispatcher(scheduler)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTestScope(dispatcher: TestDispatcher): TestScope = 
    TestScope(dispatcher)
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class MainActivityE2E {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject lateinit var testScheduler: TestCoroutineScheduler
    @Inject lateinit var testDispatcher: TestDispatcher
    @Inject lateinit var testScope: TestScope
}


 @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }


    @Test
    fun endToEnd_Test1() =
        testScope.runTest {
        /*test code*/
    }
```